# Can we block/restrict the user from typing the e-mail from some time period through office js Addin

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I need to freeze/restrict/block the user to type any key into the e-mail body for particular time period, through office js addin.
So is there any way to disable the key events or any other way so that user cannot edit/type for some time.

I tried some solutions related to setting the body readonly but it didn't worked.

I'm expecting the code through which I can restrict/block the user so that he/she is not able to type any key/letter/word into the e-mail for some time period, and I'll will display the message of "please wait" into the add-in pane until the given time is completed.

Comment: My outlook is, 
Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20164) 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

> So is there any way to disable the key events or any other way so that user cannot edit/type for some time.

No, the Office JavaScript API (OfficeJS) doesn't provide anything for that. But you can display a dialog box which prevents any input by using the [displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=word-js-preview#office-office-ui-displaydialogasync-member(1)) function. Read more about that in the [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) article.

Note, you can post your feature suggestions to https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions. The Office Add-ins team will consider them when planning if they get enough votes.